# php - Website cannot be displayed

Tags: php

**Below is the Code**

```
<?
include('config.php');

// table name 
$tbl_name=temp_members_db;

// Random confirmation code 
$confirm_code=md5(uniqid(rand())); 

// values sent from form 
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$country=$_POST['country'];

// Insert data into database 
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(confirm_code, name, email, password, country)VALUES('$confirm_code', '$name', '$email', '$password', '$country')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if suceesfully inserted data into database, send confirmation link to email 
if($result){
    // ---------------- SEND MAIL FORM ----------------

    // send e-mail to ...
    $to=$email;

    // Your subject
    $subject="Your confirmation link here";

    // From
    $header="from: your name <your email>";

    // Your message
    $message="Your Comfirmation link \r\n";
    $message.="Click on this link to activate your account \r\n";
    $message.="http://www.yourweb.com/confirmation.php?passkey=$confirm_code";

    // send email
    $sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
}

// if not found 
else {
    echo "Not found your email in our database";
}

// if your email succesfully sent
if($sentmail){
    echo "Your Confirmation link Has Been Sent To Your Email Address.";
}
else {
    echo "Cannot send Confirmation link to your e-mail address";
}

?>
```

Comment: Do you get anything as error message in your source code /apache logs? Try to describe your problem as precisely as possible.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Maybe you need to use the full PHP tags `<?php` instead of `<?`

Comment: nothing is displayed on the site

Comment: Make sure to enable error reporting, it will tell you where the problem is. And don't use short tags even if they are enabled.

Comment: help yourself ! First remove all code and test with just echo "Hello world !"

Comment: local host page is working fine...but the above page is not diplaying anything

Comment: Put ini_set('display_errors', 1); in the first line before the include and report again if you get any errors

Answer (score 0):

In your line `$tbl_name=temp_members_db;` -- is temp_members_db a constant defined (via `define('temp_members_db','some_value')` in config.php? Or is it supposed to be a string? Or is it a variable name?  This might be a problem you overlook ...

Answer (score 0):

add those lines to the top of your code:

```
ini_set('diplay_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(-1);
```

You will see the reason why nothing is displayed.

Additionally, add `echo mysql_error()` to see info about query errors:

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);
echo mysql_error();
```

Is `temp_members_db` a constant? If not, wrap into quotes:

```
'temp_members_db'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use full `<?php` tag and enable error reporting. Once enabled, see what it says. Since there is no indication of what is in config.php, there could be several problems with above code:

1. What is `$tbl_name=temp_members_db;`? I guess it shoud be `$tbl_name = 'temp_members_db';`.
2. Are `$_POST` values set?
3. Is SQL connection open?

But please, make sure to provide more information in future.